# Ошибка при установке jeremykenedy/laravel-auth

Tags: php, laravel, openserver

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth#installation-instructions,хочу](https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth#installation-instructions,%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%83) поставить,но при вводе php artisan migrate выдает эту ошибку.Как решить.

Comment: Этот пакет создает таблицу `users`, у вас уже есть такая таблица, отсюда и ошибка

Comment: чтобы работал поиск, текст ошибок нужно вставлять _текстом_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто переводим текст ошибки и станет понятно что не так. В вашем  случае - таблица `users` уже существует. Можно в файле миграции задать другое имя таблицы или перед созданием удаляем таблицу, если существует.